# Refresh automático apenas se modal Bootstrap não estiver aberta

Tags: javascript, modal

Olá, tenho uma página que mostra ocorrências em aberto e preciso que ela se atualize a cada 60 segundos (). Porém a mesma página abre um modal para o cadastro de novas ocorrências e se o modal estiver aberto quando do momento dos 60 segundos o refresh fecha o modal. (Isso acontece).

Minha dúvida é como posso saber que existe um modal aberto e então não executar o refresh ? Tentei  a função abaixo mas não funcionou. Ela já abre a página com o alerta de modal aberta.

```
          function timeRefresh(time) {
if (window.parent.jQuery('.modal-content').length > 0) { alert ("modal aberta"); return;} else {
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);", time);
        alert ("modal fechada");
      }}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pode tentar isso:

```js
    function timeRefresh(time) {
        if (document.querySelector('.modal.show') !=null) {
            alert("modal aberta");
            return;
        } else {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", time);
            alert("modal fechada");
        }
    }
```

Um exemplo em funcionamento:

https://jsitor.com/eYArZadpc

```js
function timeRefresh(time) {
  if (document.querySelector('.modal.show') != null) {
    alert("modal aberta");
    return;
  } else {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", time);
    alert("modal fechada");
  }
}

setTimeout(timeRefresh, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado mas ele passa direto como se a modal não estivesse aberta.

Comment: Putz, acertou em cheio........ salvou minha vida, OBRIGADUUU. Porém talvez para outros possa haver uma questão, na primeira vez que ele roda e encontra a modal aberta ele aborta o refresh da página, mas na segunda vez se a modal ainda estiver aberta ele faz o refresh.

Comment: Mil perdões, seu código está perfeito. Eu que esqueci de tirar o time refresh do body onload.